# How can I update the composer version that is being used inside my ddev containers?

Tags: docker, composer-php, ddev

Currently my docker/ddev setup is running Composer version 1.10.6 2020-05-06 inside the container.

I would like to make the composer version inside the container be 1.10.7 2020-06-03.

I found one way to do it: `ddev exec sudo composer self-update`, but it's not permanent. The container reverts back to using 1.10.6 after a ddev restart.

In all of my searches, I can't find a way to update the documents that create the container so they update composer permanently. I don't need it to attempt to update every time I start my container, I just need to be able to tell it now to permanently change over to the version I want.

An additional piece: adding `RUN sudo composer self-update` to the .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile makes it attempt to update every time, which is not ideal. I want to update when I'm ready, as I also need to update my test servers to match versions.

I added that command to my Dockerfile and it updated to 1.10.7. I removed the command from my Dockerfile so that it doesn't update every time I restart ddev. When I restarted ddev (without that command in the Dockerfile) it reverted composer back to 1.10.6.

*Where* is it getting the instructions to use that version? I need to find that and tell it to use 1.10.7 instead. I don't want it to update itself every time I do `ddev restart`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ddev, but I assume what you are doing is based on a Dockerfile. If so, can you do the `composer self-update` there, such then when you rebuild the image, you get the latest version?

Comment: halfer, yes defintely. But then it's updating every time it builds the container. I want to choose when to update. For example, we recently updated the composer version on our test servers and so want to update it for the local environment as well. But if I have the local environment auto update itself each time the container starts, it will end up ahead of our servers. I want to be able to set the version for the containers and not update automatically. Is that even possible?

Comment: I think what I am about to say is the same as rfay's comment - unless there is something special about ddev, you only need to rebuild your Docker image when you want the update. Otherwise just use the existing one (development envs) or pull it from a registry (clean continuous integration envs).

Comment: Out of curiosity: even if I completely understand that being on the latest version is always a good idea,but is there any good reason to do this? Even if you build your container now, adding the latest available version of Composer, this will also get outdated, and thus a rebuild is needed. On the other side. what do you gain from this? Is there anything not working in 1.10.6, but fixed in 1.10.7?

Comment: Nico, in this particular case, we upgraded composer on one of our servers to cure an error, and so needed to update our local environments to keep everything matching. That's why I wanted to specify my version and not have it continue to update after that. We don't want to keep updating just to update, but only because we had a reason.

Comment: @LeraA could you please change the accepted answer to the one that uses `composer_version` ? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I didn't try that one, so I can't confirm it. I could uncheck the one that worked for me, but that doesn't seem good either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer is dramatically outdated; the correct answer is the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019553/215713) by @Dig)

It's not normally important, but you can add a .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile with these contents:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
RUN composer self-update
```

And your composer will be updated during the image build process.

Comment: Thanks, rfay. I added another paragraph at the bottom of my question about that very thing. If I add that to my Dockerfile, it's going to check for an update every time, as I understand it. I don't want it to auto-update, since I also need to make sure my servers are on the same version as my local environments. I think I'm still stuck.

Comment: No, the .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile only gets built the first time you start the project (until you upgrade ddev). That's the great thing about it. Give it a try, you've got nothing to lose :)

Comment: Oh that sounds so good. How does it know to rebuild it now, in the middle of my project, since I add that line to the bottom? Because the file changed, it will rebuild?

Comment: When I add that line to the .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile it does indeed update composer in the container to 1.10.7 when I restart ddev. That's great, that's what I wanted. But I believe that it will attempt to update composer every time I do ddev restart. Right? Because ddev restart rebuilds the image and consults the Dockerfile with the update command every time.

Comment: I tried taking the 'RUN composer self-update' command out of the Dockerfile after it updated to the desired version 1.10.7. I hoped it would stay at that version, and with the command removed from the Dockerfile, it would no longer check to update itself every time I ddev restart. However, without that command, a ddev restart puts composer back to version 1.10.6. So it looks like that command MUST remain in the Dockerfile, and therefore composer will be updated every time they issue a new version and not just when I want to update it according to our schedule.

Comment: Again, the .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile is only built the first time you `ddev start`, until you update ddev and it has a different BASE_IMAGE. It's wonderful for all the reasons you're looking at. It only builds once, at image build time, not every time you start or restart.

Comment: Can you help me understand why 'ddev restart' caused it to revert the composer version back, if it's not building more than once?

Comment: Did it build again because I changed the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, every time you change the Dockerfile in any way it rebuilds.

Comment: Thank you rfay! And I really appreciate you sticking with me through this whole thread.

Answer (score 3):

Randy's suggestion worked well for me, however I've also found an alternative solution which involves less typing.
Read the project config.yaml and it explains how the Composer version can be changed.
This file is found in ~/yourprojectname/.ddev/config.yaml.
The first lines of the file are the configuration used and the remaining lines of the file explain the configuration alternatives available. Enjoy :)
*# if composer_version:"" it will use the current ddev default composer release.

# It can also be set to "1", to get most recent composer v1

# or "2" for most recent composer v2.

# It can be set to any existing specific composer version.

# After first project 'ddev start' this will not be updated until it changes*

Comment: This looks like what I needed. :)